# Почему при подаче на вход значения end появляется ошибка?

Tags: python

```
lst = []

while input() != 'end':
    lst += [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: У вас **два** инпута на один оборот цикла вообще-то

Comment: потому что питон не понимает, чего вы ожидаете от команды int("end")

Comment: Что и в каком порядке вы вводите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое случится, если вы введёте число, а потом end.

На один оборот цикла у вас приходится два инпута. В первом вводите, видимо, число, и оно просто теряется. Потом вы вводите `end`, и эту строку уже обрабатывает ваш генератор списка, и не справляется с преобразованием в число.

Comment: точно, спасибо!